# !Drawing a shape from unordered list of coordinates Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[image: The list of coordinates plotted]

Is there any algorithm/function to obtain a result like this?
I can't use a convex hull algorithm because the rectangle in the center won't be plotted

[image: Result]

If this can help the coordinates can be a list of tuples or index of a matrix containing the whole picture

---

**Update**

[image: External shape only using TSP algorithm]

Computational time : 4.14 s

Number of points : 140

Comment: But if the list is unordered, there are n! possible shapes, and there is no "inherent" valid one. Perhaps you can use the Traveling Salesman (TSP) or a heuristical variant to connect these in the most "*sensical*" way, although even that will not always work.

Comment: I don't understand, do you already have the list of coordinates? Or you want to generate from scratch that figure? What have you tried so far to produce the result?

Comment: @toom501: he has coordinates, but not in a (sensical) order. He wants to generate an order, such that it shows a "regular" shape, and not a chaos of lines between the coordinates.

Comment: You can for example start with a random point, look for the closest point, and connect, and then subsequently search for the closest of that point (excluding already visited ones). But again, this can sometimes fail. You can also post-process this with making swaps that improve the overall quality, but again, it is not always going to work.

Comment: An alternative is using the *active contour modeling* (snake method) of computer vision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model this can sometimes work, but as already said :) some cases will fail.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem for the answers , you said that in some case it will fail, increasing the number of coordinates can help or it'll make it worse (considering the n! of possible shapes)? The Traveling Salesman (TSP) can be useful but the problem is that the 2 shape are divided

Comment: If the number of coordinates increases, then typically the quality will increase. You can detect if there are two shapes, for example by considering the "shape" closed in case one can not find a coordinate in a small area around the coordinate, and then begin the process with the remaining coordinates.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'll try implementing it on python and i'll update the results

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle as t

points = [(0, 0), (0, 9), (9, 9), (9, 0), (0, 0)]

for p in points:
  print(p)
  x, y = p
  t.goto(x, y)
```

This code iterates over the points in `points` list. Turtle goes to each point that I declare in `points` list.
This code makes a square.

Comment: https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/SmoggyFuchsiaNotification#main.py